# Complete balanced (signed) residue System of an odd modulo m

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that if $m$ is odd then $\frac{(-m+1)}{2}, \frac{(-m+3)}{2}, \cdots, \frac{(m-3)}{2}, \frac{(m-1)}{2}$ is a complete residue system modulo m.

I understand the [definition of a complete residue system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Residue_systems) but is having a hard time incorporating the odd part of this statement.

Comment: Suggestion: take $m$ to be an **even** number (just pick one), calculate the listed elements and see why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

If $r_0, \ldots, r_{m-1}$ is a complete residue system modulo $m$ and $k$ is an integer, then
$r_0-k, \ldots, r_{m-1}-k$ is a complete residue system modulo $m$ as well.

Note that $k=\frac{m-1}{2}$ is an integer as $m$ is an odd number. Since $0, 1, \ldots, m-1$
is obviously a complete residue system modulo $m$ we conclude that
$$ \frac{(-m+1)}{2}=0-\frac{m-1}{2},\frac{(-m+3)}{2}=1-\frac{m-1}{2}, \ldots, \frac{(m-1)}{2}=m-1-\frac{m-1}{2}$$
is a complete residue system modulo $m$, as well.

Answer (score 2):

Let  $\,m = 2n\!+\!1\,$ so $\,(m\!-\!1)/2 = n,\,$ Your sequence is $\,-n,-(n\!-\!1),\ldots,-1,0,1,\ldots,n\!-\!1,n,\,$ which is a sequence of $\,m = 2n+1\,$ consecutive integers. It is just the standard [complete residue system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Residue_systems) shifted left by $\,n,\,$ i.e. mapped by $\,x\mapsto x-n,\,$ which is a bijection mod $\,m.\,$

**Remark** $ $ This system is sometimes preferred since it may introduce simplifications, e.g. the smaller numbers may simplify calculations [as here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/88448/242), and it may help exploit innate reflection (negation) symmetry, e.g. in [this additive form](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2267/242) of Wilson's theorem (sum of all elements $\!\bmod n$).

Comment: More generally, [by the Pigeonhole Principle,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/24192/242) any set of  $m$ integers that are pairwise incongruent $\!\bmod m$ form a complete residue system, [for example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1866966/242) $m$ consecutive integers in an arithmetic progression having step-size $\delta$ copime to $m$ (OP is case $\delta=1)\ \ $