# Given a C.R.S, does there $\exists$ one with half magnitude.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Suppose $x_1,x_2,...,x_b$ is a Complete Residue System (CRS) mod $b$.

is there a CRS say $y_1,y_2,...,y_b$ s.t. $\vert y_i \vert \leq \frac{b}{2}$ $\forall i = 1,2,...,b$

I want to say you CAN find one, namely, does the following work for mod $4$:

take $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ be $\{4,9,14,19\}$

then $4 \in [0]_4$, $9 \in [1]_4$, $14 \in [2]_4$, $19 \in [3]_4$

I claim $y_1,y_2,...,y_b$ is $\{0,1,2,-1\}$

which is still a CRS, has 4 elements AND

$0 \in [0]_4$, $1 \in [1]_4$, $2 \in [2]_4$, $-1 \in [3]_4$

Making $y_1,y_2,...,y_b$ = $\{0,1,2,-1\}$ a CRS modulo 4.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Use a least *magnitude* residue system $\,0, \pm1, \pm 2,\ldots \ \ $

Comment: so what you're saying is to show that such a CRS exists to use a more simple example? instead of 4, just using 1 or 2 works as well

Comment: Yes, there is a least *magnitude* CRS for any modulus (convention: choose $n$ (vs. $-n)$  modulo $m = 2n$, e.g. $\,0,\pm1,\pm2, 3\pmod{6}.\ $ Note that this is a sequence of $m$ consecutive integers (balanced around $0$) and 
 any sequence iof $m$ consecutive integers is a CRS mod $m$ (just a shift of the standard CRS).

Comment: ohh wow gotcha, so this new CRS $y_1,...,y_b$ is a "shift" if you will of my original one by a certain magnitude? so there's always a least magnitude for any given modulus . THANKS!

Comment: Yes, e.g. [see here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1151636/242)