# Modulo operator to short-cut counter-clockwise degrees

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am trying to short-cut the following with modulo, but it is not working for 90 and 270 degrees. What is the correct short-cut?

\begin{equation}
\delta'=
    \begin{cases}
        \delta & \text{if } 0 \le \delta \le 90 \\\\
        180 - \delta & \text{if } 90 \lt \delta \le 180 \\\\
        \delta - 180 & \text{if } 180 \lt \delta \le 270 \\\\
        360 - \delta & \text{if } 270 \lt \delta \le 360 \\\\
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Trying: `\delta % 90`

| delta | expected delta-prime | calculated | equal? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | TRUE |
| 30 | 30 | 30 | TRUE |
| 45 | 45 | 45 | TRUE |
| 60 | 60 | 60 | TRUE |
| 90 | 90 | 0 | FALSE |
| 105 | 75 | 75 | TRUE |
| 130 | 50 | 50 | TRUE |
| 150 | 30 | 30 | TRUE |
| 180 | 0 | 0 | TRUE |
| 200 | 20 | 20 | TRUE |
| 220 | 40 | 40 | TRUE |
| 230 | 50 | 50 | TRUE |
| 270 | 90 | 0 | FALSE |
| 280 | 80 | 80 | TRUE |
| 300 | 60 | 60 | TRUE |
| 320 | 40 | 40 | TRUE |
| 330 | 30 | 30 | TRUE |
| 350 | 10 | 10 | TRUE |
| 360 | 0 | 0 | TRUE |

Comment: It is the unsigned distance from a nearest multiple of $180$, i.e. the absolute value of the *least magnitude* remainder mod $180$, i.e. $\,\delta' = |\delta \bmod_{\ell}\! 180|,\,$ where $\bmod_{\ell}\!$ uses a [balanced residue system](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1151636/242) (least magnitude remainders).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer:
$$
\delta' = \bigl\lvert \operatorname{mod}(x - 90, 180) - 90 \bigr\rvert.
$$
The graph of $\delta'$ as a function of $\delta$ is a [triangle wave](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Triangle_wave). (I'm assuming that this function is periodic every $360$ degrees, but you can restrict the domain to just $[0, 360]$ if you desire.)

[image: Triangle wave.]

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you are looking for a way to specify the *reference angle* for a given angle $\delta$ expressed in degrees.

Perhaps you should consider$\mod 180$ rather than $\mod 90$.

The reference angle is the positive angle between $\delta$ and the nearest whole multiple of $180$.

There is a unique integer $n$ such that $180n\le\delta<180(n+1)$. That is, such that $n\le\frac{\delta}{180}<n+1$. Using the *floor* function, we have that $n=\lfloor\frac{\delta}{180}\rfloor$.

So we have $180\lfloor\frac{\delta}{180}\rfloor\le\delta<180\left(\lfloor\frac{\delta}{180}\rfloor+1\right)$

The reference angle $\delta^\prime$ is the smaller of the two positive distances between delta and the two extremes of the inequality.

That is, $\delta^\prime$ is the smaller of $\delta-180\lfloor\frac{\delta}{180}\rfloor$ and $180\left(\lfloor\frac{\delta}{180}\rfloor+1\right)-\delta$.

This gives the definition of the reference angle as follows:

$$ \delta^\prime=\min\left\{\delta-180\left\lfloor\frac{\delta}{180}\right\rfloor,180-\left(\delta-180\left\lfloor\frac{\delta}{180}\right\rfloor\right)\right\} $$

Check and you will find that for angles such as $\delta=90^\circ$ and $\delta=270^\circ$, the value of $\delta^\prime$ will be $90^\circ$.